# What is that icon that looks like a ships wheel with a line through it and how do I remove ir?

Tags: google-account

[image]I've tried every thing to remove this.Help!

Answer (score 0):

that would be the location icon. By the looks of it, your location service / gps has been turned off. This means when you use maps applications, it won't be so accurate. You may preserve a little energy by turning off location service. Please go to the main "settings" on your phone and you can find the location option there.

Answer (score 0):

Likely "GPS off".

The icon is believed to be (intentionally) enabled by some carriers. It likely involves rooting and modifying the framework (or using an Xposed module, e.g. [Sense Toolbox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-sense-toolbox-answer-to-htc-sense-t2733409)) to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold this notification, this will show you which application is resposible for that icon.
If it is third-party application you can uninstall or force stop it and if it is system app reply with screenshot.

Comment: This icon is on the _right_ side instead of the _left_, which means it corresponds to a _status_ instead of a _notification_.